# SQL find average of kg delivered per student in a each area

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

```
school
| id      | area       
|       1 |      area1
|       2 |      area1 
|       3 |      area1 
|       4 |      area2 

class
| id      | school     | students  |
|       1 |          1 |     2     |
|       2 |          2 |     28    |
|       3 |          3 |     22    |
|       4 |          4 |     4     |

deliveries
| id      | kg         | classid   |
|       1 |      120   |     1     |
|       2 |      80    |     1     |
|       3 |      20    |     1     |
|       4 |      200   |     2     |
|       5 |      150   |     3     |
|       6 |      14    |     2     |
```

I need to sum up the average of kg delivered per student in a each area.

For area1 that should amount to (120+80+20+200+150+14)/(2+28+22) = 11.23 But I can't figure out how to write that query. I guess I have to use some kind of subquery to first sum up students in area1 (52), before I sum kg delivered and divide on students?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a subquery to sum the students because if you used a plain join, then the `class` records will be duplicated due to more than one record associated with a class in the `deliveries` table.

The subquery will calculate the students per area. The outer query calculates the deliveries per area. In the expression `max(t.area_students)` is used because each deliveries record will have the total number of students associated with that delivery.

```
select school.area, sum(deliveries.kg)/max(t.area_students) as kg_per_student
from school
inner join class on school.id=class.school
inner join deliveries on class.id=deliveries.classid
inner join
    (select area, sum(students) as area_students
     from school
     inner join class on school.id=class.school
     group by school.area) t on school.area=t.area
group by school.area
```

Answer (score 0):

> > First > Join first two tables based on ID, and take t1.area,t2.classid,sum(t2.students) grouping by t1.area,t2.classid. Save this resulting query as an alias.
> >
> > Second > Join the above result with the third table on alias.classid = t3.classid while summing(t3.KG).
> >
> > Third > On your top most Select statement just do a alias1.sumColumn / alias2.sumColumn.